# What exactly happens in virtual memory when I call a function like printf in Linux?

Tags: kernel, memory, virtual-memory

I'm asking about functions like printf that a lot of processes might use and also need the help of kernel for stuff like system calls.

What is the step-by-step description in detail for what happens? Because I'm a little confused in this area, I have these questions:

1. Are the instructions for the printf function inside of the kernel part of our user process? And when it tries to execute printf, we do a JMP to that kernel location within the same user process, but we go into kernel mode? Or is there a context switch and a kernel process executes this?
2. Do all of the processes that execute functions like printf map to the same physical memory location when they call printf in their virtual memory?
3. Overall, what are the situations that non-kernel processes use the kernel part of the virtual memory?

[image]

Comment: read the code of glibc you'll see. syscall instruction on x86_64, Intel's manual will tell you about it. Process don't get mapped into physical memory, don't know what you mean. Read Intel's manual.

Comment: @神秘德里克 what do you mean processes don't get mapped into physical memory? when i said that i obviously meant pages of that virtual memory space belonging to that process get mapped into frames of physical memory.

Comment: Process has tones of Pages, some may map to same physical address as other process(like the same file mmap), some may not, not so sure your question until I read the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. `printf` is [implemented by the C library](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), it’s not part of the kernel. (The kernel does have its own equivalent, more or less, but that’s not available to user processes.) So a user process calling `printf` doesn’t call into the kernel immediately. If `printf`’s output gets written¹, that happens by calling [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), which is handled by the kernel (well, there’s a small wrapper in the C library, but it’s minimal); the process invokes the corresponding system call, and control switches to the kernel, but still within the context of the same process.
2. Code pages from executables or libraries are only loaded once into memory (for the same version of the underlying file), so yes, `printf` maps to the same physical address, if it’s provided by the same library.
3. The kernel part of virtual memory is only accessible from kernel code.

¹ Strictly speaking, `printf` writes its output to a buffer, which might not be written anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for answer, So regarding question 1 : at which point we jump into kernel section of our process virtual space? when we call write or only when we do a system call?

Comment: Generally, the process calls `write`, which is a wrapper in the C library; that sets everything up as appropriate, and invokes the system call. The switch to the kernel happens as a result of the system call (that’s why it’s a system call).

Comment: thanks, also regarding the thirds answer, i updated the picture the previous one was not complete. ( i also made another thread for follow up questions on this answer, didn't want to spam in comments)

Comment: `printf` _may_ end-up calling `write()`. It adds some text to a stdio buffer which may eventually be written.

Comment: @StephenKitt also can you please edit your third answer and explain it a bit more? by kernel mapping do you mean mapping to physical memory? because i didnt say anything about mapping to physical memory

Comment: @John I was referring to the part of memory reserved for the kernel.

Comment: @StephenKitt but what do you mean by only accessible from kernel code?  i thought a normal  process can jump into kernel part of its virtual memory because of a system call based on answer 1?

Comment: @John a system call doesn’t involve a normal process jumping into the kernel. A system call involves a normal process asking the CPU to switch to the kernel and run a call, identified by number, on its behalf. You don’t jump to an address in the kernel’s end of the address space (at least, not in Linux on x86); you invoke some other mechanism (on x86, `INT 0x80`, `SYSENTER`, or `SYSCALL`, depending on the specific ABI being used). See [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/) and [its follow-up](https://lwn.net/Articles/604515/) for details.